# How to attach additional information to browser report-to/report-uri/report-endpoints reporting api?

Tags: content-security-policy

I currently have a Content Security Policy (CSP) that is setup and recording some information, but want to add some addition information to get recorded. For example I would like to record information about the current logged in user, and on some pages the where the user is doing formative online quizes, I'd like to see if I could include information about answers the user had selected before an error occured or the browser crashed or network failed.

Reading some of the documentation on the javascript ReportingObserver API like.
https://developer.chrome.com/articles/reporting-api/
It says I should be able to attach additional information to the report with a callback on the ReportingObserver API. But I can't find any example for how I should do this.

Does anyone know how I could add additional information to a browser report?
Otherwise, does anyone know if these reports are sent to the server with cookies?
I have seen that some information can be added by setting the URL for the report endpoint to include information but I think this can only be set server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For good reasons, it is not possible to intercept or extend the JavaScript event `SecurityPolicyViolationEvent` - in case there is a violation, it must bei issued unmodified by the client (the web browser).

However, a much simple approach would be to enrich the reporting endpoint by additional query parameters, that reflect the state of currently shown document. For this scenario the server would have to provide a new version of the reporting URI for each step that has been passed, which is probably not desired when using single page applications that pass data back to the server via AJAX only.

Additionally CSP violations are submitted to the server with all valid cookies of the current scope. Thus, one could define a session cookie in the client application which is sent automatically to the server. Due to the lack of using the `HttpOnly` cookie flag, users would be able to tamper with that information (just as a security side note).

Example using additional query params to the reporting URI and a custom application cookie:

#### Response for the document at `https://myapp.example.org/quiz`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 12:26:02 GMT
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: ... report-uri https://myapp.example.org/@http-reporting?csp=report&requestTime=1679919962482608&quiz[step]=13
```

The reporting URI has some additional information like below:

- `&requestTime=1679919962482608` which can be used to aggregate multiple violations for a given document → all violations can be aggregated on the server side by this request time (in microtime format)
- `&quiz[step]=13` for instance contains the application specific details for the quiz you mentioned initially and the current passed/finished step

#### Request to a potential CSP violation sent back to the endpoint

```
POST /@http-reporting?csp=report&requestTime=1679919962482608&quiz[step]=13
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/csp-report
Cookie: MyAppQuizStep=13;
Host: myapp.example.org
Origin: https://myapp.example.org
Referer: https://myapp.example.org/quiz

{"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://myapp.example.org/quiz","referrer":...}}
```

The request is submitted using the additional query params to the reporting endpoint, besides that, there are some more details in the request that can be used on the server side:

- `Cookie: MyAppQuizStep=13;` reflecting the current quiz state; cookie was set in JavaScript without using `HttpOnly` flag
- `Referer: https://myapp.example.org/quiz` reflecting the previously viewed document URI (which is also present in the CSP violation payload in the body of that request)

#### Final remark

CSP violations might be tampered, there is no guarantee that the request to the reporting endpoint was a real application error or the result of some user fiddling around in the browser console or sending direct requests to the reporting endpoint directly.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do some additional testing with setting values in cookie. Just to check if the cookies that are sent with delayed CSP reports, are the cookies with the values that would have existed at the time of the error would have occured, or cookies from the time the message is sent. And do some additional testing using report-to urls on different domains, with different priorities and network delays just to make sure I am understanding how different browsers are handling retries, and browsers switching between networks.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of solving this:

1. Using the reporting-api as you have mentioned for all policy related events:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SecurityPolicyViolationEvent. I haven't tested this, but I would start here and modify the output.
2. The dirty way is to add URLs to an unused CSP directive (could be manifest-src or prefetch-src or others). To do this you need to dynamically modify the CSP for every page load. If you set "prefetch-src 'self' https://<datapoint1>.nosuchtld/<datapoint2>/<datapoint3>/<datapoint4>" the full CSP in your report will provide the data. If the full CSP is not reported, insert this in the relevant directive.

NOTE: Be aware of the possibly privacy implications of doing this! You might be providing data that could identify the user, which could be in violation of privacy regulation. Make sure to strip any unnecessary information away.

Will cookies be sent? Normally cookies will be included if host, path and secure flag matches, but there might be exceptions for CSP reports, but this may not be consistent across browsers.